# Stored procedure in SQL Server (order by desc)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that will give the latest records i.e., order by added date this is my procedure....

```
  select distinct top 5 videos.videoid,videos.videotitle,videos.videoname,
   convert(varchar,videos.posteddate,106) as  posteddate,videos.approvedstatus,
   videos.videoimage,(ISNULL(videos.views,0.0)) as [views],videos.privacy,
    (isnull(videos.rating,0.0)) as rating,videos.userid,
  users.userid,users.username from videos  left outer  join users on
videos.userid=users.userid
   where videos.approvedstatus='Y' and videos.privacy='P'
 order by  posteddate desc
```

but it is not giving latest records

when i execute the query

```
select * from videos order by posteddate desc
```

it is giving exact records. but  stored procedure is not giving exact records.
can u help me, thank you.

---

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - "store procedure is not giving exact records". Please add to your question: what are you expecting, what is actually returned and why it is wrong.

Comment: i want videoid,videoname,videotitle,views,userid,username,rating,posteddate,from users table and videos table

Comment: Just a nitpick: it's a store**d** procedure (it's **stored** in SQL Server) - not a "store" procedure (has nothing to do with a store or any kind).

Comment: @Surya sasidhar, provide some i/p data, and o/p data for both the queries you have tried... without data its hard to determine the problem...

Comment: i have a doubt in my videos table some of the values in rating columns is null is there any problem with null values in a column (rating)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY videos.posteddate`

```
  select distinct top 5
     videos.videoid,
     videos.videotitle,
     videos.videoname,
     convert(varchar,videos.posteddate,106) as  posteddate,
     videos.approvedstatus,
     videos.videoimage,
     (ISNULL(videos.views,0.0)) as [views],
     videos.privacy,
     (isnull(videos.rating,0.0)) as rating,
     videos.userid,
     users.userid,users.username
  from
     videos
     left outer join
     users on videos.userid=users.userid
  where
     videos.approvedstatus='Y' and videos.privacy='P'
  order by
     videos.posteddate desc
```

Your original is the equivalant of `ORDER BY convert(varchar,videos.posteddate,106) DESC`

So you are sorting by "dd mon yyyy" string, not the desired actual datetime (yyyy-mm-dd hh etc)

I guess this is SQL Server 2000: from memory SQL Server 2005 will not accept this ambiguity

Comment: ok Mr.gbn thank you for response i will check it and inform you

Comment: ya i got it Mr. gbn i simple remove ..
  convert(varchar,videos.posteddate,106) as  posteddate, 
and i change like this
 videos.posteddate and now it is giving correct i mean latest videos